# NoScript settings by default have Allow Scripts Globally (dangerous) ticked

Tags: security, noscript

I noticed that on occasion my browser has this opened by default when opening Tor Browser bundle and wont allow the appearance tag to work when I select options, but instead doesn't show any. In some instances it shows just one. Once I choose an option the security settings are needed to be restored too

Comment: What refers "this" in "… has this opened …"? What do you mean by "the appearance tag"? What options do you select? "doesn't show any", any what? What exactly are you asking?